# How to run gdb on httpd processes within a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, apache, process, gdb

I would like to get all my httpd processes, put in an array, then run `gdb` on each process, run as a cron, save output to file. For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Make a list of current httpd pid's and then run "gdb" on each one

pids=( $(pgrep 'httpd') )

for each in "${pids[@]}"
do
  echo "$each"
  gdb httpd $each >> gdbscipt.out
  echo "Done with: $each"

done
```

When I run it just runs on the first pid.

```
# ./gdbscript
2046
```

Then just stops after each pid is processed. Because it seems there is a breakpoint? within gdb after processing each pid.

I want to run it overnight a few times via cron.

Is there a better approach to running gdb on a list of active httpd processes via cron and outputting to a file(s)?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the commands (presumably in `.gdbinit`) that gdb is running each time?

Comment: you need some form of `quit` or `exit` cmd in your gdb script, right? Good luck.

Comment: Mark, I don't seem to have a .gdbinit. I have looked in /etc, and various ~ directories. So I assume when I run "gdb program pid" it runs the defaults.

Comment: The default for gdb is to attach to, and suspend, the program, then print a `(gdb)` prompt (which you won't see on your terminal, because the `>> gdbscript.out` redirects it to a file), then wait for the user to type in commands.

Comment: What do I need to do to have it advance thru all the pid's in their entirety and not suspend the program and print the "gdb" prompt? I would like to run it as a cron several times in a time frame and then go back and look at the output files later.   Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you'd like to see in the `gdbscript.out` file?

Comment: I am a neophyte with gdb. I was told it would be a good tool to troubleshoot periodic  extreme slow webserver performance, and perhaps determine if those occasional performance issues are  web server or backend database server related. So I am sorting it out as I go. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: so automating a "cycle-thru" of all running servers seems like a pre-premature optimization. You'll need to learn how to use the internal cmd-line of `gdb` before you can think of capturing that output, analzying it and constructing a logic flow based on the outputs. I know the `gdb` has a tutorial and manual website, so find those and start testing 1 PID before worrying about trying to process N number of PIDs. ;-) OK? Good luck.